# "A JDBC Driver or DataSource class name must be specified in the ConnectionDriverName property." Error

Tags: java, xml, sqlite, jpa

Hi I'm trying to create a simple JPA class using SQLite. I have everything set up then this shows up everytime I try to run main:
"A JDBC Driver or DataSource class name must be specified in the ConnectionDriverName property."
Is it because I have the wrong value for the sqlite driver name?
I can't seem to find out what the value of the property is for sqlite. Here is my persistence.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<persistence>
    <persistence-unit name="testjpa" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>
            org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl
        </provider>
        <class>entity.Discography</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionURL" value="jdbc:sqlite:C:\\sqlitedb\\repo.db" />
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionDriverName" value="org.sqlite.JDBC" />
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionUserName" value="" />
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionPassword" value="" />
            <property name="openjpa.Log" value="SQL=TRACE" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score -1):

```
org.sqlite.JDBC
```

You can download the driver [here](http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/)

Use code like this:

```
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC"); // This doesn't actually do anything useful, it just asserts you can find the class
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:test.db");
Statement stat = conn.createStatement();
stat.executeQuery("select * from table");
```

Comment: I've tried using that for the value of ConnectionDriverName but still the error persists. Plus I have sqliteJDBC driver installed already. I tried using plain old JDBC and it works but I can't seem to make it work with JPA using sqlite because of that error. Any ideas?

Comment: I tried using "org.sqlite.JDBC" as the value of the ConnectionDriverName and still the error shows. I'm trying to make sqlite work with JPA. I used JDBC before with sqlite and it works. I used the code and the driver on the link you've provided.